# How can I set odoo graph vlaues in the y-axis

Tags: graph, nvd3.js, odoo

This is my graph:

[image]

What I need is to display just the **0 and 1** in the y-axis without 0.1 ,0.2, .., 0.9

Answer (score 1):

**Graph tag**

The default type of the graph is a pie chart - to change it to a barchart change  to  You also may change the orientation.

:Example :

```
<graph string="Sales Order Lines" orientation="horizontal" type="bar">
```

Field tag

The first field is the X axis. The second one is the Y axis and the optional third one is the Z axis for 3 dimensional graphs. You can apply a few attributes to each field/axis:

- **group:** if set to true, the client will group all item of the same value for this field. For each other field, it will apply an operator
- **operator:** the operator to apply is another field is grouped. By default it's '+'.

  Allowed values are:

  - +: addition
  - *: multiply
  - **: exponent
  - min: minimum of the list
  - max: maximum of the list